# Issue with 404 Page Not Found in Category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have a website/blog setup with Wordpress.

Under **Settings** > **Permalinks**, I'm using a "Custom structure":

```
http://mywebsite.com/%category%/%postname%
```

And my `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

**What *does* work:**

- Single posts
- Pages
- Categories (e.g. `http://mywebsite.com/blog`)

**What does *NOT* work:**

- Category sub-pages (e.g. `http://mywebsite.com/blog/page/2` - when clicking the "Older Posts" link)

---

What's going on? Is there any other way (aside from the... pretty permalink above, to access the subpages under some category - e.g. by category ids, etc?)

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress searches for a post with slug **page** in category **blog**, but can not find it and return 404.

There is only one workaround - manually create rewrite rules, so it can work as you expect.

For more info see [Using Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) and find "Paged Navigation Doesn't Work" on it.